# Adding days to a date in a table - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table 'Qualified' with a column 'DateQualified'. The format for the date inputted is MM-YYYY.

However, I changed the displayed format to be: Month fmDD, YYYY. I'm trying to add 15 days to what ever the date is and display the new date.

Right now, I have this:

```
 Select TO_CHAR(DateQualified,'Month fmDD, YYYY') as "Reminder Date"
      FROM Qualified;
```

I've been trying to do some research, and it's something along the lines of:

```
 Select TO_CHAR(DateQualified + numtoyminterval(15, 'DAY'),'Month fmDD, YYYY') as "Reminder Date"
      FROM Qualified;
```

Obviously, this isn't working. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You should store dates as dates and not strings.

Comment: When I inserted the information, this is what I put in for the date:

TO_DATE('09-1996','MM-YYYY');

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `to_char(datequalified, ...)` suggests that `datequalified` **is** a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, try the below SQL

```
Select TO_CHAR(DateQualified + 15,'Month fmDD, YYYY') as "Reminder Date"
  FROM Qualified;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use DateAdd function

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, 15, DateQualified) as "Reminder Date" FROM Qualified
```

In Oracle, you can try something like this:

```
to_char(sysdate + interval '15' DAY,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Im not sure, worth a try. Good luck